# Alert dialog popping late

Tags: android

/*I have some wierd problem, inside OnMenuItemClickListener, i am calling an alert dialog which i made, but it seems like, when i call the alert dialog, it doesnt show it on right moment, only after onMenuItemClick finish. what am i doing worng?
    */

```
class MyListMenuListener implements OnMenuItemClickListener
    {

        private String TAG;

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
        {
            if (item.getItemId() == saveRoute.getItemId())
            {                   
                alertDialogSaveFile();
                //nameInput = "testone.txt";
                //some operations
//                                      ...
 //                                      return true;
            }
```

//  ...

```
/*the wierd thing is that the alert dialog doesnt show up on the same moment i call it..
only after the onMenuItemClick operation ends (with return)
and this is how my alertdialog looks like:*/

        private void alertDialogSaveFile()
{

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Save your current map");
        alert.setMessage("Please insert name for this route");
        final EditText saveNameInput = new EditText(TwittListActivity.this);

        alert.setView(saveNameInput);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                nameInput = saveNameInput.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
            }
        });
         AlertDialog ad = alert.create();
         ad.show();
    }


//Thanks!
//ray.
```

Comment: I get what you say, but it's pretty not logical to do, and not a "neat" coding, couldnt be other way, then push everything inside the okClick?

Answer (score 3):

Dialogs in Android aren't synchronous, so it's very likely that the UI thread is finishing `onMenuItemClick()` before creating/displaying your dialog (dialogs are managed by the enclosing Activity).

**Edit**: I misunderstood part of your question.  Keep the call to `alertDialogSaveFile()` where it is and put the code that actually saves the file into the `onClick()` handler.  Since dialogs in Android aren't synchronous, you need to perform the save action in the dialog callback itself.  It's not possible to show a dialog, wait for the user to respond, and then get the result from the dialog.